# Why does the $\sigma_2$ Pauli matrix correspond to 2d rotations?

Tags: lie-groups, quantum-mechanics

We can obtain a representation of the Pauli matrices through the exponential map:
$$ \exp(-i \vec{\sigma} \cdot \hat{n} \phi)= \textbf{1} \cos(\phi) - i \vec{\sigma}\cdot \hat{n} \sin(\phi) .$$

Why is it that the exponential of the $\sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ Pauli matrix specifically, which is:
$$ \exp(-i \sigma_2 \phi) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi) & - \sin(\phi) \\
\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
\end{pmatrix} $$ correspond to a rotation in 2 dimensions? It seems odd that the generator along $\hat{n} = \hat{y}$ corresponds to a 2d real rotation matrix (and not along any other direction).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but the matrix exponential of any anti-symmetric matrix $A^\top=-A$ is an orthogonal matrix (hence a rotation matrix).  since for $R=e^{A}$ we have
$$R^{\top} R=e^{A^\top}e^A = e^{A^\top+A}=e^0 = I.$$
This means that you can generate rotations in 3 and 4 dimensions as well, simply by exponentiating 3x3 and 4x4 anti-symmetric matrices.